# "SELECT FROM" Query to Mariadb in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

i'm trying to run a `"select from"` query to mariadb and here is my code.

```
var mariadb = require('mariadb');

router.get('/redirect', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
    const { payload: { id } } = req;

    console.log("in redirection function, id " + id);



const pool = mariadb.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3307,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'abc',
        database: 'db',
    });
    pool.getConnection()
        .then(conn => {

            var query = 'select id from user_credentials where id="'+id+'"';
            console.log("query is " + query + "   : end");
            conn.query(query, function (err, rows) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    throw err;
                } else {

                }

                return res.json({'resule':rows});

            });


        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("error 2" + err);
            conn.close();
        });



    console.log("nothing happened")
    return res.json({'resule':'test'});

});
```

but it only runs till this statement

```
 console.log("query is " + query + "   : end");
```

and after that it jumps to the statement "nothing happened" and returns the response. i guess it some kind of async execution and is not waiting for the thread to complete. I've tried multiple approaches but its not working.

Comment: Try knex or similar ORM

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax; how is `conn` declared?

Answer (score 1):

The line `return res.json({'resule':rows});` is returning from the callback it is in - not the containing function. Just to see what's happening, try:

```
console.log(res.json({'resule':rows}));
```

The results should be printed on the console. Then the question becomes how to get the results out. Spend some time [getting to know asynchronous Javascript](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) e.g. callbacks and promises.

Comment: i've tried this 

`console.log(res.json({'resule':rows}));`

but nothing prints on the console.

Comment: Put a `console.log...` on the line after the `conn.query...` line to make sure that you are coming back from the query. It appears to be where your code is stopping.

Comment: i've debugged the code and it jumps from this statement 
`conn.query(query, function (err, rows) `
to this 
`return res.json({'resule':'test'});`

Comment: @SultanKhan - I still think the point about `return` not returning from the desired level is the crux of the issue.  Abandon chasing it with `console.log` and think how to unravel the `return`.